# Best way to check whether the incrementor in a loop is within a certain range?

Tags: c#

I have a loop which loops up to 20.

I am using **C# 4.0** and **LINQ** (Where necessary). What's a good way to say

`"if i > 3 && < 5"`

but for various bands (eg between 3 and 5, 6, and 8, etc), without loads of if statements in the loops?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want just one check, or multiple ones? I.e. are you saying "if it's in the range 2-3 or the range 5-7 or the range 4-5 do X", or are you saying "if it's in the range 2-3 do X, if in the range 5-7 do Y, if in the range 4-5 do Z"?

Comment: The latter. SOrry for the lack of clarity.

Comment: Does the loop do anything else besides these band-specific actions? It almost sounds like you're falling into the for-case antipattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to simplify syntax, you could write an extension method:

```
public static bool IsBetween(this int num, int exclusiveLowerBound, int exclusiveUpperBound)
{
    return num > exclusiveLowerBound && num < exclusiveUpperBound;
}
```

Of course, it is debatable if `i.IsBetween(3, 5)` really is cleaner than the sample you have provided.

If really you are dealing with "various bands", you could use the efficient [Interval Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) data-structure. If performance is not an issue, you could just write a simple class yourself:

```
public class NumRange
{
    public int ExclusiveLowerBound { get; private set; }
    public int ExclusiveUpperBound { get; private set; }

    public int Size
    {
        get
        {
            return ExclusiveUpperBound - ExclusiveLowerBound;
        }
    }

    public NumRange(int boundary1, int boundary2)
    {
        ExclusiveLowerBound = Math.Min(boundary1, boundary2);
        ExclusiveUpperBound = Math.Max(boundary1, boundary2);
    }

    public bool Contains(int num)
    {
        return num > ExclusiveLowerBound && num < ExclusiveUpperBound;
    }

}
```

This will allow you to write code like:

```
var rangeToComment = new Dictionary<NumRange, string>
{
    {new NumRange(3,5), "The number 4."},
    {new NumRange(0, 10),"Single digit natural numbers"},
    {new NumRange(int.MinValue,int.MaxValue),"Integers"}
};

foreach (int number in Enumerable.Range(0, 100))
{
    var tightestRange = rangeToComment.Where(kvp => kvp.Key.Contains(number))
                                      .OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Key.Size)
                                      .First();
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", number, tightestRange.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You still need to be checking for those values, so the best option I see if to make the check a function. This makes the if clause very clean, but still provides flexibility to test for any range.

```
bool inBand(int value, int low, int high) {
  return value > low && value < high;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a switch:

```
switch(i) {
  case 3:
  case 4:
  case 5:
    // between 3 and 5
    break;
  case 6:
  case 7:
  case 8;
    // between 6 and 8
    break;
  case 9:
  case 10:
  case 11:
    // between 9 and 11
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To "hide" your magic-numbers a bit and maybe make the code a little clearer you could do something like this. It all comes down to your needs.

```
//By naming the rangeX variables something meaningful you can make your code more readable(in my mind).
var range1 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
var range2 = new int[] { 4, 5 };
var range3 = new int[] { 6 };

for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    if(range1.Contains(i)) 
    {
      //Do stuff
    }
    else if(range2.Contains(i)) 
    {
      //Do other stuff
    }
    //etc
}
```